# joblib using spacy objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, joblib, spacy

I am working with a medium sized text dataset - about a 1GB of a single text column that I have loaded as a pandas series (of type object). It is called `textData`.

I want to create docs for each text row, and then tokenize. But I want to use my custom tokenizer.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from spacy.en import English


nlp = English()
docs = nlp.pipe([text for text in textData], batch_size=batchSize, n_threads=n_threads)

# This runs without any errors, but results is empty
results1 = Parallel(n_jobs=-1,)(delayed(clean_tokens)(doc) for doc in docs)
# This runs, and returns expected result
results2 = [clean_tokens(doc) for doc in docs]

def clean_tokens(doc):
    # clean tokens and POS tags
    exclusions = [token.i for token in doc if token.dep in [punct, det, agent, prep, aux, auxpass, cc, expl, quantmod]]
    tokens = [token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.i not in exclusions]        
    return tokens
```

I am running the above functions inside main() with a call to main() using a script.

Any reason this should not work? If there is a pickling problem - it doesn't get raised.

Is there any way to make this work?